# passport js update req.user data when changing user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to update the data in my req.user when I change the user data like changing the email validation from false to true. What is the best way to do this? at the moment I run req.logIn again but this doesn't seem like a great solution.

So is there a way to update the user data in my req.user without running req.logIn again.

My Passport.js config:

```
//=============================================================================
// OAuth2.0 Setup Start
//=============================================================================
const passport = require('passport')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const User = require('../models/User')
const userLimit = require('../routes/utils/userLimit')

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log('user: ', user)
    done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj)
})

//=============================================================================
// OAuth2.0 Google Start
//=============================================================================
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: `${process.env.clientID}`,
            clientSecret: `${process.env.clientSecret}`,
            callbackURL: `${process.env.url}/auth/google/callback`,
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            User.findOne({
                $or: [{ googleId: profile.id }, { googleId: null, email: profile.emails[0].value }],
            }).then((user) => {
                if (user === null) {
                    new User({
                        name: `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        verified: true,
                        password: null,
                        picture: profile.photos[0].value,
                        googleId: profile.id,
                    })
                        .save()
                        .then((newUser) => {
                            userLimit()
                            console.log('newUser: ', newUser)
                            done(null, newUser)
                        })
                        .catch((err) => done(err, null))
                } else if (user.googleId === profile.id) {
                    done(null, user)
                } else if (user.googleId === null) {
                    done(null, false)
                }
            })
        }
    )
)

//=============================================================================
// OAuth2.0 Local Start
//=============================================================================
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ email: username }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err
            if (!user) return done(null, false)
            if (user.googleId !== null) return done(null, false)
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err
                if (result === true) {
                    return done(null, user)
                } else {
                    return done(null, false)
                }
            })
        })
    })
)
```